# Change Button Text Color Programmatically for n number of buttons without changing Text Color of other button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, tags, textcolor

I have n number of buttons in the scrollView. If click on a button its text color is changing but if I click another button the text color of the previous button remain unchanged. I want to change the previous button text color as default color while clicking another button. The behavior will be just like a segmented control. Please help me regarding this, I've providing my code below:

```
-(void) loadScrollView:(CGRect)scrollViewFrame withButtonArray:(NSArray*)buttonArray withCase: (int)ButtonCase
{
    scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:scrollViewFrame];
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(100 * 768, 40)];

    for (int i = 0; i < [buttonArray count]; i++)
    {
        adButtonOutLet = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140*i, 0, 135, 40)];
        if (ButtonCase==0) {
            [adButtonOutLet setBackgroundColor:UIColorFromRGB(0X272c2f)];
            [adButtonOutLet setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x969696) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            if (i==0) {
                adButtonOutLet.backgroundColor=UIColorFromRGB(0x000000) ;
                [adButtonOutLet setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x179d95) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }            
        }

        adButtonOutLet.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro" size:14.0];
        [adButtonOutLet setTitle:[buttonArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        adButtonOutLet.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
        [adButtonOutLet setTag:i];
        [adButtonOutLet addTarget:self action:@selector(adButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [scrollView addSubview:adButtonOutLet];
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    }
}
```

**Here is my action method:**

```
 -(void)adButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
    for (int i = 0; i < [menuArray count]; i++)
    {
        int prevTag = 0;
        if (sender.tag == i && Case==0)
        {                
            [self reloadScrollViewwithButtonTag:i];
           // [sender setSelected:YES];
            sender.backgroundColor=UIColorFromRGB(0x000000) ;
            [sender setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x179d95) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            prevTag=i;
        }

        if (Case==1) {
            sender.backgroundColor=UIColorFromRGB(0x000000) ;
            [sender setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x179d95) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            if (sender.tag==prevTag-1) {
                [sender setBackgroundColor:UIColorFromRGB(0X272c2f)];
                [sender setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x969696) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try changing all buttons style to no selected except the one that is on the sender parameter (selected button)?

```
-(void)adButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender{
    for (int i = 0; i < [menuArray count]; i++)
    {
        if (sender == menuArray[i])
        {
            //Selected code style
        }

        else{
            //No selected code style
        }
    }
}
```

Considering menuArray is an array with all buttons.
This way you check and modify all styles when a button is pressed.

Hope this could help you or at last give you a clue for resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don' understand everything in your `adButtonAction` (what is menuArray?) method but I think what you need is simple, just adapt it to your method.

First create a `NSMutableArray` to keep reference on your button list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [buttonArray count]; i++)
{
    adButtonOutLet = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140*i, 0, 135, 40)];
    [myButtonArray addObject:adButtonOutlet];
....
```

Then in you action method, set the right color:

```
for (UIButton* b in myButtonArray){
    if(b.tag == sender.tag){
         [self setSelectedColor:YES forButton:b];
         // Do what you want here
    }
    else{
         [self setSelectedColor:NO forButton:b];
    }
}
```

With:

```
-(void)setSelectedColor:(BOOL)selected forButton:(UIButton)button{
     if(selected){
        sender.backgroundColor=UIColorFromRGB(0x000000) ;
        [sender setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x179d95) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
     else{
         [sender setBackgroundColor:UIColorFromRGB(0X272c2f)];
         [sender setTitleColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x969696)forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- Apply state vise( Normal,Selected ) title color of button.
- Just persist a selected button reference as weak.
- while user clicked on button set that button state as selected instead normal.
- Change last selected button state **Normal** instead **Selected**.

Check out below code that will be help you

```
UIButton *selectedButton;
-(void)adButtonAction:(UIButton*)sender
{
        UIButton *tempButton = sender;
        if (selectedButton && selectedButton!=tempButton)
        {
            [selectedButton setSelected:NO];
        }
        [tempButton setSelected:YES];
        selectedButton = tempButton;
}
```